# Does my iptables command change the header fields in matching packets?

Tags: iptables, routing, http-proxy

I don't understand what this `iptables` command actually does.  Can someone explain?

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 10000`

I **do** understand that tcp packets destined for port 80 are redirected to localhost port 10000.  However, my specific question is this: if an incoming packet matches (ie, it is tcp and destined for port 80), then is the port rewritten in the TCP header to 10000?  And is the destination IP in the IP header rewritten to 127.0.0.1 or left as-is?

If either of the two entries above are changed, are header checksums recalculated?

And finally, if I write a TCP server on localhost listening on port 10000, and a browser gets redirected to me, how do I proxy the browser's connection if the destination IP was overwritten?  Use the Host header?

Comment: REDIRECT is only change the port and there is no lo interface nor 127.0.0.1 in this situation.

Comment: @IporSircer Are you certain about this?  From the `iptables` man page on REDIRECT: "This target is only valid in the nat table, in the PREROUTING and OUTPUT chains,  and  user-defined  chains  which  are  only  called from those chains.  It redirects the packet to the machine itself by changing the destination IP to the primary address of the incoming  interface (locally-generated packets are mapped to the 127.0.0.1 address)."